# Why does the Vscode command pallet does not work

Tags: python, django, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-catalina

The key strike work. Menu drops down. Shows nothing. Maybe files. This continue in all projects.

It also high-lights imports as if it’s not there. But the project operates just the same.

I don’t know is this is a root/path issue.

Showed others and asked around and No One has any ideas. This has been hurting my productivity and learning. Tried uninstalling and reinstalling through Brew. Problem persists.

Comment: can you show add some screenshots on what you are seeing when you press `CTRL+SHIFT+P`?

Comment: I would try installing from code.visualstudio.com instead of through Homebrew to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Uh, have you tried Ctrl+Shift+P ?

Answer (score 1):

If the keyboard combination Ctrl+Shift+P does not work, try to find any application that have system wide keyboard shortcuts that overlap.

For me my todo-app TickTick overwrote that specific command which prevented me from opening the command palette.